# Django keeps reinitiating database connection? - Django

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, django, windows-server-2008

I'm trying to get a Django app deployed... unfortunately randomly page load times are quite HIGH.

I nailed the problem down at it being the database connection.

**Apparently Django keeps having to reinitiate the connection with the database every now and then as requests get through.**

The connection takes about **9-10seconds to be initiated...** causing massive page laod times.

Specs:

- Django 1.2.3
- pyodbc and django-pyodbc
- SQL Server 2008
- Windows Server 2008 R2
- IIS7.5 with ISAPI_WSGI
- python 2.6.6

2 servers: 1 web server and 1 database server

Comment: How -- specifically -- are you running Django?  Please don't say you're running `manage.py runserver`.  Please provide the web server you're using (IIS?  Apache HTTPD?  nginx?)

Comment: IIS7.5 with the ISAPI_WSGI extension

Comment: 10 sec for each page load? even for `manage.py runserver` that's way too slow. What are you doing in your views.py?

Comment: Not all of them, some of them. When the connection to db is initiated.

Comment: How, specifically, is the WSGI interface configured?  Is it in `daemon` mode?  Please provide the configuration parameters you're using.

Comment: is your dbserver in the same machine? is your network slow? if your db server is on a diff machine, then are they connected by local high speed LAN or is the traffic getting routed through internet?

Comment: @MovieYoda: I'm sure they are connected through LAN and SQL queries seem to be performed pretty fast. It's just the connection initation.

Comment: can you manually try to connect to your Db & see if it slow?

Comment: You should try to further isolate the problem and then edit your question. I suggest running 'django-admin.py shell' multiple times to see if you can reproduce. To further isolate, try 'django-admin.py dbshell'. To even further isolate, try writing a plain python program using pyodbc to connect.